# While loop in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, synthesis

To check the synthesisability of while loop, I created one hypothetical vhdl code as follows.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity test_loop is
Port ( a : in  INTEGER;
       i : in INTEGER;
       CLK : in std_logic;
       b : out  unsigned (3 downto 0)); 
end test_loop;

architecture Behavioral of test_loop is
  --signal C : unsigned (3 downto 0) := "0000";
begin
  process(CLK)
    variable C : unsigned (3 downto 0) := "0000";
  begin
    if (rising_edge(CLK)) then
      while(a /= i ) loop
        C := C + 1;
      end loop;
      b <= C;
    end if;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I was expecting a synthesising error because I think the loop has no definite bounds. I cant simulate this code too because it goes infinite for a /= i . But surprisingly this code got synthesised in Xilinx 13.1 ISE without showing errors. What might be the reason ?

**UPDATED:**

changed C into variable. Still the code is getting synthesised. RTL view is obtained as -

[image]

Comment: Because C is a signal not a variable. See the difference between signal assignment semantics and variable assignment semantics.

Comment: Use ISE's schematic view to see the logic circuit that you synthesised.

Comment: @Brian. I changed the signal C to variable and used variable assignment. But it still got synthesised without errors.

Comment: RTL view added.

Comment: Well that's ... interesting. If you posted the code as code, I might have tried it in ISE14.4. But I can't compile your picture. Too bad.

Comment: Okay Let me try.

Comment: I generally recommend for beginners to not use loops or variables. The semantics of how they work in VHDL is very confusing to someone coming from C or other programming languages.

Comment: Added text code sample.

Comment: you should include your library/use statements in your code snip

Comment: (ISE14.4) ... `ERROR:HDLCompiler:981 - "/home/brian/Projects/ghdl/testcase/testcase/test_loop.vhd" Line 20: Non-static loop limit exceeded`(both with variable and signal) ... older ISE versions had more bugs.

Comment: Oh then it has to be some problem with my Xilinx 13.1 !??

Comment: "Oh then it has to be some problem with my Xilinx 13.1 !??" Very likely. That version is ancient. There are petrified trees younger than that.

Comment: Above was targeting Spartan-6 - a newer FPGA. Even ISE14.4 targeting Spartan-3 compiles this ... because it uses an older VHDL compiler (with different bugs). Learn the importance of simulation. Synth tools are allowed to take liberties with code because they can assume it has already passed simulation ... it has, right? :-)

Comment: Hm bugs . I guess so. Feeling good to see the error. Concepts are clear now :-). I think the synthesiser took while loop like If or something to generate that RTL netlist.

Comment: And regarding loops ... use for loops, they have well defined bounds and can synthesise well.

Comment: Feel free to wrap all this up into an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the comments under the post, it has been confirmed that it's nothing but a bug in Xilinx 13.1 ISE. Seems like it uses old buggy compilers depending on the chosen FPGA. The above code is not synthesisable as I expected. The code was not synthesised in newer versions like ISE 14.4 and Vivado. It threw *non-static loop limit exceeded* error as the loop condition has no definite bounds.

Comment: Xilinx Synthesis Technology (XST) User guide under XST VHDL Language Support, VHDL Constructs Supported in XST, VHDL Statements, the table VHDL Loop Statements, you'd only find two loop statement constructs with a while loop conspicuously missing. Referring to IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis) still in effect for identical language in 11.3 in 2009, while loops aren't suppored for synthesis (8.8.9 Loop statement). The XST UG layout matches Clause 8. Syntax from 1076.6). There was no expectation while loops would synthesize. 14.7 XST supports while loops for newer devices (Brian's Spartan-6).